Free space solution of inhomogeneous static Klein-Gordon equation in spherical coordinates
In the context of nuclear physics I have the following equation for a static potential $v(\boldsymbol{r})$:
$$
( k^2 - \Delta ) v = f(\boldsymbol{r})
$$
with $f$ a real valued function with $ \int f d^3 \boldsymbol{r}  = 1$, $k$ real positive, $v(r = 0) \neq \infty$ and $v(r \rightarrow \infty) = 0$.
Question:
What is the expression of $v$ in spherical coordinates (with the development in spherical harmonics) ?
Hint with the Coulomb potential:
In case of a Coulomb potential and a radial-only dependent function f(r) we have:
$$
- \Delta v_c = f(r)
$$
and then using the Laplace expansion and after integration we get:
$$
v_c = \frac{1}{r} \int_0^r f(r') r'^2 d r' + \int_r^{+ \infty} r' f(r') d r'
$$
Guess:
So for the equation:
$$
( k^2 - \Delta ) v = f(r)
$$
where f(r) is again only radial dependent. We should have the following solution:
$$
v \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{e^{ - k r}}{r} \int_0^r f(r') r'^2 d r' + \int_r^{+ \infty} r' e^{ - k r'} f(r') d r'
$$
I want to have the generalized development for an angular ($\theta, \varphi$) dependent $f(\boldsymbol{r})$ with the spherical harmonics expansion but it is super hard to find it. Maybe someone have a simple clue or even have the full development ?
Clue:
Ok I need to use first the Yukawa potential expansion in spherical harmonics:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.00716 eq. (12)
Thank you for reading

Finaly found it, it is just a green function and the Yukawa extension (which is quite uncommun I guess?):
$$
v = \int \frac{e^{- k \Vert \boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r'} \Vert}}{4 \pi \Vert \boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r'} \Vert} f(\boldsymbol{r'}) d^3 \boldsymbol{r'} 
$$
Using the missing Yukawa's expansion:
$$
\frac{e^{- k \Vert \boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r'} \Vert}}{\Vert \boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r'} \Vert} = k \sum_{l = 0} I_l(k r_<) K_l(k r_>) \sum_{m = - l}^l (-1)^{m} Y_l^m (\Omega') Y_l^{- m} (\Omega)
$$
$I$ and $K$ modified spherical Bessel of 1st and 2nd kind. So we have the expression for $v$:
$$
v = \frac{k}{4 \pi} \int \sum_{l = 0} I_l(k r_<) K_l(k r_>) \sum_{m = - l}^l (-1)^{m} Y_l^m (\Omega') Y_l^{- m} (\Omega) f(\boldsymbol{r'}) d^3 \boldsymbol{r'} 
$$
so that should give:
$$
v = \frac{k}{4 \pi} \sum_{l = 0} \sum_{m = - l}^l (-1)^{m} Y_l^{- m} (\Omega) \int_{4 \pi}   Y_l^m (\Omega') \left( K_l(k r) \int_0^{r} f(\boldsymbol{r'}) I_l(k r') r'^2 d r'+  I_l(k r) \int_r^{\infty} f(\boldsymbol{r'}) K_l(k r') r'^2 d r' \right) d \Omega'
$$
